# How to append xml encoding tag to XML Result set

Tags: sql, xml

I have two issues which arise from the following SQL code:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(BookID int primary key,
                   Title varchar(50),
                   Author varchar(50),
                   Pages int);

INSERT INTO @tbl SELECT 1,'The Book', 'The Author', 20
INSERT INTO @tbl SELECT 2,'Another Book', 'Another Author', 20
INSERT INTO @tbl SELECT 3,'Book', 'Author', 20

SELECT Book.Title,
       (SELECT Details.BookID Ref, Details.Author, Details.Pages
        FROM @tbl Details
        FOR XML RAW ('Details'), type)
FROM @tbl Book
FOR XML RAW ('Book'), ROOT  ('Books')
```

The result set returned is:

```
<Books>
  <Book Title="The Book">
    <Details Ref="1" Author="The Author" Pages="20" />
    <Details Ref="2" Author="Another Author" Pages="20" />
    <Details Ref="3" Author="Author" Pages="20" />
  </Book>
  <Book Title="Another Book">
    <Details Ref="1" Author="The Author" Pages="20" />
    <Details Ref="2" Author="Another Author" Pages="20" />
    <Details Ref="3" Author="Author" Pages="20" />
  </Book>
  <Book Title="Book">
    <Details Ref="1" Author="The Author" Pages="20" />
    <Details Ref="2" Author="Another Author" Pages="20" />
    <Details Ref="3" Author="Author" Pages="20" />
  </Book>
</Books>
```

Issue No.1: The details tag is repeated multiple times for each book, I only want one.
Issue No.2: I would like to append `<?xml version="1.0"?>` to the top of the result set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be multiple ways to do this.  Here is one:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(BookID int primary key,
               Title varchar(50),
               Author varchar(50),
               Pages int);

INSERT INTO @tbl SELECT 1,'The Book', 'The Author', 20
INSERT INTO @tbl SELECT 2,'Another Book', 'Another Author', 20
INSERT INTO @tbl SELECT 3,'Book', 'Author', 20


;WITH cte (XMLRESULT) AS (

SELECT Book.Title,
   (SELECT Details.BookID Ref, Details.Author, Details.Pages
    FROM @tbl Details
    FOR XML RAW ('Details'), type)
FROM @tbl Book
FOR XML RAW ('Book'), ROOT  ('Books') 

) 

SELECT  '<?xml version="1.0"?>' + XMLRESULT FROM cte
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The output has changed from nicely formatted XML tags on separate lines to just text, is there a way for preserving that formatting?

Comment: Not sure really.  It is always on one line for me in SSMS, even your original post.

Answer (score 0):

First issue is easily dealt with by adding a `WHERE` clause into the subquery:

```
SELECT Book.Title,
       (SELECT Details.BookID Ref, Details.Author, Details.Pages
        FROM @tbl Details
        WHERE Details.BookID = Book.BookID --<-- Here
        FOR XML RAW ('Details'), type)
FROM @tbl Book
FOR XML RAW ('Book'), ROOT  ('Books')
```

Re: the XML declaration, I'm not sure that's so easy to achieve - most people seem to solve it by converting to text and just jamming the string on the front.

Comment: Thank you that totally slipped my mind (the WHERE part). The second issue SQLDBa's response solves